# Sub-Query result in the PIVOT IN-List exceeds max limit

Tags: teradata

I am putting together what is currently a pretty simple pivot query.

```
select 
*
from
some_table
    pivot (max(col_c) for col_b in (select distinct col_b from some_table where col_d =  'A'*  )) d
where col_d = 'A'
```

The problem is that I keep getting `Sub-Query result in the PIVOT IN-List exceeds max limit` back.  I'm getting this error when the sub-query is returning only 18 rows.

What is the actual limit here?  Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately when using a subquery to define the FOR clause values, the current limit is only 16 rows. This limit does not apply if you supply a list of literal values, so you could potentially run the subquery and use the results to dynamically build the PIVOT query (either in a Stored Procedure or in some client-side scripting language).

Comment: Additionally there's no way to order the pivot columns returned by the subquery. Both issues combined render this feature useless :-(

Comment: Wow, that's really...disappointing. @dnoeth, do you mean the ordering of the pivot columns isn't deterministic, or just that I can't control it?

Comment: Both, the order can't be controlled and and might change with each execution

Comment: Indeed it does change.  Back to the drawing board!